# Android drawable resources with numbers

Tags: android, resources, numbers, drawable

I'm implementing a code-snipped in my android application, where i open a popup window. This popup window takes a little drawable and put it around itself. This png resource is named ***.9.png**. I can rename it as i prefer, but if i remove the **9** the output of the resource is different. With the number the png is displayed correctly; otherwise it is stretched on the entire window.
What does it mean? Does the framework do something special seeing this number. Moreover i noticed that that when this resourced is used in code or XML, the **.9** has to be omitted...so i think that it is for the framework.
Could someone explain it in detail?

The code comes from the QuickAction3D package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a `*.9.png` naming indicates a [Nine-patch image](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html), which is an image with annotations to modify stretching behaviour.

Comment: Well, i read and programmed a lot on Android, but i've never seen/read this, however, i think it's a very useful feature.